# Eclipse Stacktrace System.err problem

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling, printstacktrace

All of a sudden my printStackTrace's stopped printing anything. When I give it a different output stream to print to it works (like e.printStackTrace(System.out)) but obviously I would like to get it figured out.

Comment: Does `System.err.println("Hello");` produce anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your launch profile, on the common tab, check to make sure "Allocate console" is checked in the "Standard Input and Output" section.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if some library you are using is not redirecting the standard err with the System.setErr(PrintStream) method.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the problem but the Console view in Eclipse has some toggle buttons to show/hide the console when output from either stdout or stderr changes.

Is it possible that you've clicked the stderr button accidentally?